# Delete rows that contains no information on Tweet text on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, twitter

I´m  trying to remove rows containing blank texts or in tweet texts column. But I have tried in different ways counting the rows that only contain whitespace or counting the leading spaces and trailing spaces but to get a criterion to eliminate it.

```
ID    tweet           WhiteSpaceCount HaveWhiteSpace
0    this is a text        0              False
1                         0              False
2   Hello im fine         0              False
```

I want to delete all the rows that don´t have any information on the tweet column.

Code here:

```
def extractAndSave(api, name):
    # Creamos una lista de tweets:
    previous_date = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
    query_date = date.today()
    name = name
    tweets = API_EXTRACTOR.search(q=name + "-filter:retweets", result_type='recent', timeout=999999, count=200,
                                  end_time=previous_date, tweet_mode='extended')
    # Podemos crear un dataframe como sigue:
    tweet_list = []
    for tweet in tweets:
        tweet_list.append(tweet.full_text)
    datos = pd.DataFrame(data=tweet_list, columns=['TWEETS'])

    # CREANDO COLUMNA DE ID
    id_list = []
    for id in tweets:
        id_list.append(id.id)
    id = pd.DataFrame(data=id_list, columns=['ID'])

    # CREANDO COLUMNA DE ID
    creado_list = []
    for creado in tweets:
        creado_list.append(creado.created_at)
    creado = pd.DataFrame(data=creado_list, columns=['FECHA_CREACION'])

    # CREANDO COLUMNA DE nombre de usuario
    user_list = []
    for usuario in tweets:
        user_list.append(usuario.user.screen_name)
    usuario = pd.DataFrame(data=user_list, columns=['USUARIO'])

    # CREANDO COLUMNA DE FUENTE
    fuente_list = []
    for fuente in tweets:
        fuente_list.append(fuente.source)
    fuente = pd.DataFrame(data=fuente_list, columns=['FUENTE'])

    # CREANDO COLUMNA DE ME GUSTA
    like_list = []
    for like in tweets:
        like_list.append(like.favorite_count)
    like = pd.DataFrame(data=like_list, columns=['ME_GUSTA'])

    # CREANDO COLUMNA DE RT
    rt_list = []
    for rt in tweets:
        rt_list.append(rt.retweet_count)
    retweet = pd.DataFrame(data=rt_list, columns=['ME_GUSTA'])

    # CREANDO COLUMNA DE IDIOMA
    idioma_list = []
    for idioma in tweets:
        idioma_list.append(idioma.lang)
    idioma = pd.DataFrame(data=idioma_list, columns=['IDIOMA'])

    # CREANDO COLUMNA DE IDIOMA
    quote_list = []
    for quote in tweets:
        quote_list.append(quote.is_quote_status)
    quote = pd.DataFrame(data=quote_list, columns=['CITADO'])

    # CREANDO COLUMNA DE IDIOMA
    location_list = []
    for location in tweets:
        location_list.append(location.user.location)
    location = pd.DataFrame(data=location_list, columns=['LOCACION'])

    # CONCATENANDO DATAFRAMES
    datos = pd.concat([datos, id, creado, usuario, fuente, like, retweet, quote, idioma, location], axis=1)

    # Dropear toda la fila si la columna tweets viene vacia.
    datos['pass/fail'] = np.where(datos['TWEETS'].astype(str).str.fullmatch(r"\s*"),'FAIL','PASS')

    datos['CONTEO_ESPACIOS']= (datos['TWEETS'].str.startswith(" ") | datos['TWEETS'].str.endswith(" ")).sum()
                    

    # Hora de publicación
    datos['HORA_PUBLICACION'] = datos['FECHA_CREACION'].dt.hour
    datos['DIA_SEMANA'] = datos['FECHA_CREACION'].dt.day_name()

    # Extrayendo solo los tweets del día anterior
    datos['FECHA_CREACION'] = pd.to_datetime(datos['FECHA_CREACION']).dt.date
    datos = datos[datos['FECHA_CREACION'] == previous_date]

    print(datos)

    # Guardando en dataframe.
    return datos
```

Comment: Please include the code you wrote that is not working

Comment: I've moved your code from your (now deleted) answer into the question so everyone can see it. In general if you have more to add to your question you can press the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69635564/edit) button under the question. The "Post Your Answer" button should only be used to provide an answer to a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of removing rows that you don't need, keep only the ones you do need:

```
df = df[df["tweet"].str.strip().str.len()>0]

>>> df

   ID           tweet  WhiteSpaceCount  HaveWhiteSpace
0   0  this is a text                0           False
2   2   Hello im fine                0           False
```